# Download/Fastboot Mode Broken

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, odin

I have the Samsung J5 Pro (SM-J530F).

Two years ago I installed TWRP via Odin and download mode and it worked great. Since then I never entered download mode again because I installed all my roms with TWRP.

Now, I am trying to enter download mode in order to install my original Android 9 (from Sam-Mobile),  through Odin, and it's not working, like the download mode has been deleted somehow...

I tried every possible way, with the bottoms (power, volume down and home), through TWRP, with ADB but it is not working!!

If you have any suggestions, I would like to hear...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117270/discussion-between-the-student-and-alecxs).